# How set dynamically small icon notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-notifications, android-statusbar

How set dynamically small icon notification in status bar? **Notification.Builder.setSmallIcon(int icon)** this code set static icon from Resources. Need set icon dynamically

**Example**

[image]

Icons temperatures changes dynamically

Help please.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a **new notification with the new icon** and **use the same ID when creating the notification**.
It will replace the old notification and hence change the image in the notification.

And if you do not want to have so many icons in your drawable folder. Create a [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) from string and then set it as the smallIcon.

Comment: Thanks for BitmapDrawable

Comment: does that serve your purpose?

Comment: Don't. Because setSmallIcon use int icon, not bitmap